# Can a string literal type and type "string" be mixed and used as key in a mapped type?

Tags: typescript, types

I'd like to define a mapped type where the keys `'foo'` and `'bar'` are of type `number` and all other keys are of type `string`

My first intuition was to solve this with a conditional type like so:

```
type FooOrBar =  'foo' | 'bar';

type MyMappedType = {
        [key in FooOrBar | string]: key extends FooOrBar ? number : string;
}

var x: MyMappedType = {
    foo:  1,   // Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.(2322)
    bar:  2,   // Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.(2322)
    baz: 'I am a string'   // ok!
}
```

[Example 1](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=3.9.7#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nA8gJwEIENlQLxSgcgDMF8oAfAgI03wG4Aoe0SKAWRFfTEgBMAVcNFwBvennHiA2gGsIIKAEsAdrAQoMWCgGdgyZQHMAugC4os+RAAewCEp5bVSNJigB+KEoCuAW0oQspjp6SvoMAL6MAG4ulqbsnNwQ-II4UKISxHCmUACMADTiAPSFUAIs+F6+-qQKDkpwwFDoWloK+krolAA20MBwUMzQ+EEG+AB0ABQATADMU1MAlGLi1MjZUwV4xaUpFT5+yDV1DU0tbR3dvf2DBCMh49Nzi8t41ABepvgAkk3eTVB3fSkLYlODSACE9DCQA)

The problem here is that typescript narrows the typealias `FooOrBar | string` down to type `string` in the key. So in fact typescript evaluates this type to

```
type MyMappedType = {
        [key in string]: key extends FooOrBar ? number : string;
}
```

so the condition `key extends FooOrBar` is always false and the type-definition is useless for my need.

My second intuition was to use an intersection type:

```
type FooOrBar =  'foo' | 'bar';

type MyMappedType = {
        [key in FooOrBar]:number;
} & {
        [key in string]:  string;
};

var x: MyMappedType = { //       Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.(2322)
    foo:  1,
    bar:  2,   
    baz: 'I am a string'  
}
```

[Example 2](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=3.9.7#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nA8gJwEIENlQLxSgcgDMF8oAfAgI03wG4Aoe0SKAWRFfTEgBMAVcNFwBvennHiA2gGsIIKAEsAdrAQoMyALoAuJQFcAtpQjIGAXygAyKKIkSZcxSoDOwZMoDmOvK-dKP5gz0AG6YUAAe2mwcXLwCLCJQAPRJdnjx0Pj6RiakCs5QSnDAUOjOzgoeSuiUADbQwHBQzJm+nvgAdAAUAEwAzD09AJRi4sRwUVAAjAA0o3jUyJM9M+LzUNQAXlH4AJKlBqVQbf6kUPRmQA)

But this doesn't work either.

Is there any possibility to define a type like this in typescript?

Answer (score 1):

You could create properties for each of your indexing cases, e.g.

```
type numberLiterals = 'foo' | 'bar'

type myMappedType = {
    numbers: { [key in numberLiterals]: number; };
    strings: { [key: string]: string }; 
}

var x: myMappedType = {
    numbers: {
        foo: 1,
        bar: 2,
        // zzz: 5 -> not assignable
    },
    strings: {
        fo: '',
        fooo: ''
        // baar: 1 -> not assignable
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAdgrgWwEYQE4BkCWw0EMA2AzlALxQDkAZgPbXlQA+FSuq5AUO6JFAiALK4wkACYAVcNDIBvdlHmxEKVIQBcUaVADaAawggomGIuRosOVAUIBddfFOoA3FAC+juQsLBURgOZqNbT0QdS8fGF9bKDC-V2d2F04AN1YoAA91PkFhCHFJUg0PeXtlANkFCqgaanUARgAaIsqWVHUAJkbKhQB6bqgAL0H1AFYoAFoAPlhqYChcQkJMXxhcJHwIJpdOz28-MqaKmnVycm2u6pqKDi75XqgWVjrxqZgZuYWllbWNisSXIA)

Comment: Well yes, that would work, but it's more a workaround than a solution. I'd rather define types for my code-structure than adjusting my code-structure to types.

Comment: @Simon I think it's not possible to do this with strings because `[key: string]` already allows any string (including those in your union type). You could use numbers though.

Comment: @Simon Actually after some digging, you can change the intersection to a union and it should work as you intended. Not a fan of it for the above reason still though.

Comment: Union will allow initial assignment, but you won't able to access "string index" props (`x['baz']`) https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAHgLhgJQKagE4BMA80MCWYA5gDQz5HEB8MAPiuiNjgOQBmIIr9MrARgEMMrcmACuAW36oMtALwwA3gCgY6mJxBIYARlJqNQjDoBM5dYfVCAXklYBJGIMnOKUQiVYqAvipVwANoCgjasALoBAHRaMIqsggA2ECAw-BggANaoYKxAA

Comment: @AlekseyL. Ah you're right, and the `FooOrBar` properties also become a `string | number` when accessing them. Guess my first intuition was right then